# Re-enable Setting app that has been disabled

Tags: google-play-store, settings

I mistakenly disabled my phone's Settings app after Play Store marked it as harmful. I can no longer change my setting or get into the phone setting again.

What do I do?

Comment: If you have a computer available, you could e.g. try re-enabling it via [adb](/tags/adb/info) – see e.g. [these questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Badb%5D+disable+enable+app) for details.

Comment: factory reset will fix it

Comment: May we know the device model and Android version? It's quite surprising that the Settings app could be disabled. Was this done through Play Store's Play Protect, or did you disable it manually?